# how to use arcgis locate widget with electron?

Tags: electron, arcgis, electron-builder, arcgis-js-api

I'm new with ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript.
I'm integrating the map with the locate widget button, following the instruction written in the official tutorial: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-locate/

I'm using electron to execute the app (v29.1.1).

With electron, the widget is unable to locate the position due to permissions.

It get the following message:

There was an error. Please check the location permissions on your browser and operating system.

I think that the problem is with electron permission, but I didn't find any solutions for days.

I've already checked the permissions on my browser.